# 403 error page is not working in my web service which is running on a Tomcat 7

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, custom-error-pages

I am developing a Rest Web Service with Jersey. The service is running on Tomcat 7. Under my "WebContent" folder I have put three xml files. One is named error403.xml, other error404.xml and the other one is error505.xml. Also in my web.xml I have the following lines:

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error403.xml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.xml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/error405.xml</location>
</error-page>
```

When Tomcat answers to bad request due to http errors 404 and 405 maps correctly and take my files instead of tipical html error files. So error404.xml and error405.xml are shown correctly but my problem is that when a client try to connect and causes an 403 error, Tomcat does not map the answer to my error403.xml so Tomcat sends a blank (empty answer).

Does someone have any idea of this? Any answer will be really appreciated

Comment: I am going to explain better my problem. I have a rest service now running. My problem (and my headache) is that before including the error-page in my application web.xml all was running ok. Tomcat mapped http error to its typical html error answers. But if I include the error page, Tomcat asnswer sometimes with htttp error 403 instead of 404 error. I tried to put also in error-page tag the error403.xml, but Tomcat answers with the following message:                                     HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat,14Feb201513:54:33

Comment: The answer header is:                                                                HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 14 Feb 2015 13:54:33 GMT                                                                                                     
And the body is empty:                                                                            <data contentType="null" contentLength="0"><![CDATA[]]></data>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem including in my web.xml the following:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>  

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

AppExceptionHandler is a class  that is called when http errors (403, 404, 405) occurs. What I want is when any commented http errors occurs Tomcat replies with a xml instead of its typical html.The definition of the class is:

```
package exception;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import connectionDB.Constants;

@WebServlet("/AppExceptionHandler")
public class AppExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    protected void doHead(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    private void processError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Analyze the servlet exception
        //Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        String servletName = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
        if (servletName == null) {
            servletName = "Unknown";
        }
        String requestUri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
        if (requestUri == null) {
            requestUri = "Unknown";
        }

        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("application/xml");

        //Set response content type
        response.setContentType("application/xml");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><MW_ERROR_RESPONSE><MW_VERSION>1.0</MW_VERSION><MW_ERRORDESC>Wrong user</MW_ERRORDESC></MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>
        out.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><MW_ERROR_RESPONSE><MW_VERSION>" + Constants.MW_VERSION +"</MW_VERSION><MW_ERRORDESC>");
        if(statusCode == 405){
            response.setStatus(405);
            out.write("Client Error Request - HTTP method not allowed. Please change your HTTP method in your request</MW_ERRORDESC></MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>");
        }else if(statusCode == 404){
            response.setStatus(404);
            out.write("Client Error Request - Request not found or invalid URI: " + requestUri  + ". Please change your URI request</MW_ERRORDESC></MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>");
        }else{
            response.setStatus(403);
            out.write("Client Error Request - Unknown error</MW_ERRORDESC></MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>");
        }
    }
}
```

So when the client send a bad request the answer is:

```
<MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>
<MW_VERSION>1.0</MW_VERSION>
   <MW_ERRORDESC>Client Error Request - Request not found or invalid URI: /***/***. Please change your URI request</MW_ERRORDESC>
</MW_ERROR_RESPONSE>
```